# Is it possible to track a gps device which is remotely placed within a network?

Tags: android, gps, wifi

I want to do an app which tracks the remotely placed device such as key-chain. I was incorporating a GPS unit into the locator device i.e., I embedded a GPS receiver, micro controller, WiFi Transmitter and a battery which is useful for power. The micro controller get the GPS co-ordinates from the GPS unit and store in the registers and it should capable of being sent to the mobile over a hotspot whenever it gets connected with a mobile WiFi. So that the transmitted Geo Co-ordinates are passed to the mobile and there the distance of current location to the co-ordinates is measured and it should navigate to the device where it was placed through the data passed into it.So that it can find the device through the GPS system which was embedded. Many people forgot the keys where they left so that I was developing.Please give me a detail about this.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.apartmenttherapy.com/stop-losing-your-keys-and-stuf-145705

Just go with this link this may useful to your research